# If line through point $P(a,2)$ meets the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ at A and D and meets the coordinate axis at B and C

Tags: analytic-geometry

If line through point $P(a,2)$ meets the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ at $A$ and $D$ and meets the coordinate axes at $B$ and $C$ so that $PA$, $PB$, $PC$, $PD$ are in geometric progression, then the possible values of $a$ can be
$(A)5\hspace{1cm}(B)8\hspace{1cm}(C)10\hspace{1cm}(D)-7$

---

I could not solve this question, I inferred from question that $PA\cdot PD=PB\cdot PC$ and $PA\cdot PD=PT^2$, where $T$ is the point of tangency.
But I could not solve further. This is a multiple correct choice type question. Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find this question?

Comment: In my jee preparation book?But why are you asking so?@Aretino

Comment: To be sure it is not from an ongoing contest.

Comment: Do you know how is it to be solved?@Aretino

Comment: How do you know that $PA\cdot PD=PT^2$?

Comment: This theorem is applicable in circles,may be this is applicable in ellipses also.

Comment: No, that theorem is not applicable to ellipses in general. Trying the various proposed values of $a$ with GeoGebra, none of them seems fit to the job. Are you sure the text is correct?

Comment: Yes the text is correct.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: Let me ask you a question. Do you believe that at least one of the options is correct?

Comment: @mathlove,Sir i got this question from a reliable good book,do you find the four options incorrect?

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: Thank you for the reply. So, do you have the answer? If so, can you share it with us?

Comment: @mathlove,the answer posted by Sathyaram Ganpathy below seems convincing and reasonable but i could not understand it.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: Thank you for answering my questions. Please let me ask you to check that you don't have any typos in your question.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: Thank you. I wanted to help you, but it seems **to me** that there are no correct options...

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia: If you don't believe my answer is reliable (but I performed my calculations with Mathematica and checked the result with GeoGebra, so I'm quite sure my result is correct) you can easily check with GeoGebra that the given options are all wrong: just construct the diagram for a given position of $P$ and check if $PA$, $PB$, $PC$ and $PD$ are in geometric progression or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WLOG we can take $a>0$, $A$ nearer to $P$ than $D$ and notice that the only case we must consider is when $B$ is the intersection with $x$-axis and $C$ is the intersection with $y$-axis, for otherwise those four segments cannot form a geometric progression. If $b$ is the $x$ coordinate of $B$, the equation of line $PB$ is $y=2(x-a)/(a-b)+2$ so that the $y$ coordinate of $C$ is $y_C=-2b/(a-b)$.

Combining this equation with that of the ellipse, we can readily find the $y$ coordinate of $A$ and $D$:

$$
y_A= \frac{2 \left(3 \sqrt{a^2-2 a b+9}-a b+b^2\right)}{a^2-2 a b+b^2+9},
\quad 
y_D= \frac{2 \left(-3 \sqrt{a^2-2 a b+9}-a b+b^2\right)}{a^2-2 a b+b^2+9}. 
$$

We know that $PA:PB=PB:PC=PC:PD$ and this relation also holds for the $y$ components of the segments, that is:
$$
(y_P - y_A):(y_P - y_B) = (y_P - y_B):(y_P - y_C) = (y_P - y_C):(y_P - y_D).
$$
Inserting here the expressions given above for $y_C$, $y_A$, $y_D$, as well as $y_P=2$ and $y_B=0$, we can solve for $a$ and $b$. The only acceptable positive solution is:
$$
a=3 \sqrt{2+\sqrt{13}}\approx 7.10281,
$$
but of course the opposite value, by symmetry, is also a valid solution. As you can see, this is not far from your $(D)$ choice but it is not the same. So the exercise is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ellipse,
[Ellipse image(Click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kzvt.jpg)

The Equation of line is,
$$
y-2=(x-a)tan\theta,
$$
The ***P(A)*** is,
$$
P(A) = (\space a+(r)cos\theta,2+(r)sin\theta\space ),
$$
where ***r*** is the distance between ***P(A)*** and ***P(a,2)***.

Solving equation of the straight line by putting ***x=0*** and ***y=0***,we get
$$
P(B)=(\space a-2cot\theta,0\space)\space and \space P(C)=(\space 0,2-(a)tan\theta\space),
$$
We also get distances,
$$
PB=\sqrt(\space(2cot\theta)^2+4\space)=2cosec\theta,
$$
and
$$
PC=\sqrt(\space a^2+(atan\theta)^2\space)=asec\theta,
$$
Similarly we get ***PD*** and ***PA*** by solving straight line and ellipse equation,
Now
$$
PA.PD=PB.PC,\space PB/PA = PD/PC
$$
$$
4a^2/(4 + 5sin^2\theta) = 2a/sin\theta.cos\theta,
$$
$$
solving, we \space get\space a=(\space(13-5cos2\theta)/2sin2\theta\space).
$$
$$
then \space we \space get,\space a=(\space (13-5(\space 1-tan^2\theta)/(1+tan^2\theta)\space)/4tan\theta/(1+tan^2\theta)\space)
$$
We then get a quadratic equation of ***tan(theta)***,
Solving putting ***D=0*** we get,
$$
a^2\space>36,\space therefore \space a\space>6
$$
The options are ***(B) and (C)***.